# Why is Godzilla released significantly later in Japan?

Tags: distribution, monsterverse, godzilla-2014

When looking at the different [release dates](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0831387/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_dt_dt) of Hollywood's 2014 take on [*Godzilla*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0831387/), it appears as quite striking that the release for Japan is signifantly later, more than 2 months to be precise, than those for the rest of the world, which are all around the middle of May.

I usually don't care that much about release dates, but seeing that it is a Hollywood version of an iconic part of modern Japanese culture, **I wondered if there is any official word why this release is so significantly later than all the others.** While skepsis about the new version could be a factor, the movie on the other hand, and in contrast to *Emmerich*'s 1998 take, has been more or less sanctioned by *Toho Studios*, the makers of the Japanese original(s), up to the point of collaboration.

(And please forgive me for ignoring China in the list, whose release date lies in between the Japanese and the others. This was only to simplify the question a bit and to concentrate on the contextually more important Japan. But maybe the reason for the Chinese delay is somehow related?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've no definitive answer, but here's an [interesting article](http://variety.com/2014/film/asia/japanese-audiences-anticipate-new-godzilla-1201185049/) with a suggested reason:

> Japan, however, will be the last major market to view the latest
>   Hollywood iteration of the iconic franchise that Toho [a Japanese film, production and distribution company] launched in 1954
>   with the first of 28 made-in-Japan Godzilla pics: The studio plans to
>   release “Godzilla” on July 25, nearly six weeks after its U.S. bow,
>   but **not out of any uncertainty about its success**.
>
> **“That’s just the best timing,” explains Ogura [A Toho PR Rep]. “It’s when big movies
>   are released here.”**
>
> One recent example is the Hayao Miyazaki animation “The Wind Rises,” a
>   Toho release that opened on July 20, 2013, and became the year’s
>   highest-earning pic with $117 million.
>
> **One reason for this timing is that Japanese schools do not begin their
>   summer break until mid-July.** But Toho, Ogura emphasizes, does not
>   consider “Godzilla” kiddie fare. “Of course, children will be able to
>   see it – it’s rated for all ages,” he says, “but our primary target is
>   adults.”

Comment: Well, of course we can't ever see anyone's true motives and thoughts, but an official PR-statement seems like a *"definitive" enough* answer to me.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: My thoughts too :)

Comment: I took the freedom to add some highlights of the actual answer.

Comment: I guess an additional factor was also that Japan is the only country where a dedicated different studio releases it, instead of Legendary/Warner. Thus they have probably more freedom/desire in adapting to local interests rather than some otherwise global release strategy. That's probably why Japan is such an outlier. Still I wonder about China, but well, that wasn't the question anyway.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Ask a different question about China then :P :)

Comment: Haha, no, really don't care enough (and one could drive this ad absurdum). On the other hand, this site is definitely lacking in *Godzilla* questions, compared to the awesomeness of this movie at least. ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: [This page](http://www.godzilla-movies.com/community/forums/topic/34443) is actual an interesting read. It says China only releases some 34 foreign films A YEAR... If that's true, that's crazy. I guess in the climate the film release date isn't THAT important.

Comment: Wow, it was also interesting that *Iron Man 3*'s Chinese version featured extra footage and this seems kind of a trend, maybe to get one of the rare 34 places.